# Binding #define used as constant

Tags: objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

The code I am trying to bind puts a very important key in one of the .h files:

```
#define xAppKey @"REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_APP_KEY"
```

This value is then reused throughout the ObjC code. I am suspicious that in the binding process, this value does not carry through. Based on a few other threads on SO, that seems to be the case, at least. Is my problem likely something else, or is there a chance this value is not being honored in the wrapped code?

I'm sorry if my objective-c terminology is off, I know nothing about it.

**EDIT**

I just wanted to clarify what may not have been evident. By "binding" I am referring to binding it to monotouch as a native library. If that was clear already, carry on...

Comment: I would try using something like a `public const String AppKey = "MY_APP_KEY";`, as binding compiles the code first, which makes the macro disappear.

Comment: I don't have to use xAppKey anywhere in the code I am writing against in c#, but it is used in the ObjC code that I am binding.

Comment: The full problem I am having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351191/monotouch-binding-to-objectivec-library-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of having a `#define` in an Obj-C `.h` is to allow it to be replaced by the application leveraging the library. In this case, your (Obj-C) library is probably distributed as sources only.

But you want to create (Xamarin.iOS) bindings for it. So you need to **compile** this library, and compiling will fix the value of the `xApiKey` once and for all.

Your aim is probably to expose this `xApiKey` to the consuming application through Xamarin.iOS. You'll have to modify the `Obj-C` library to use a property instead of a constant, then bind the (static) property accessors through `Xamarin.iOS`

Comment: Actually, everything related to xApiKey happens under the hood, so I don't need it exposed to me. There are getters to retrieve xApiKey, but no setters. So I just wanted to ensure that if I set the #define and compiled that the value would carry through.

Comment: yes, if you hardcode the `xApiKey`, it'll be forged into the binary. Make then sure you don't distribute the binary, nor the binding, as it'll contain your ApiKey...

Answer (score 4):

xAppKey is a macro. It will not be bound at all. On the contrary. On pre-compile time it will be replaced with `@"REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_APP_KEY"` and then compiled as if this string was repeated all the time.

For exactly this reason some experts suggest replacing them with constant strings. These experts may be right. However, I like the #define.

And for exactly this reason you should not add any comments to the #define statement.

```
#define xAppKey @"REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_APP_KEY" // This is the application key
```

Things like that will almost certainly cause compile time errors which may be hard to understand. 
Example:

```
NSLog (@"%@", xAppKey);
```

That works fine withot the comment, because it will be converted to:

```
NSLog (@"%@", @"REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_APP_KEY");
```

But with the comment it will be converted to:

```
NSLog (@"%@", @"REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_APP_KEY" // This is the application key);
```

And that's not gonna compile.

Comment: Do you know how that does/does not relate to binding to monotouch? It sounds like it should be fine, because when I create the .a it should do the macro replacement you are referring to?

Comment: About the comment thing: Comments will not appear in macro expansions in any C99-compliant compiler (which means you're safe in both GCC and Clang).

Comment: All right, I'll try that with the comment the other day. Just read that somewhere. @lordscarlet you are right of course. A macro cannot be bound to anything external at link time.

Comment: @HermannKlecker but if everything is happening internal to the objc compiled code, should I be OK? I'm sorry for the lack of knowledge here, I'm mostly trying to narrow down the possible root of my problems. If I know this is not a problem, I can keep digging into other possibilities.

Comment: @lordscarlet: A lack of knowledge is why we are here for. And SO is execllent at that. Frankly, I do not know monotouch very well. AFAIK it creates binaries which you then need to link to your iPhone project or vice versa. But the interface is on *.o (or whatever) binary objects level. In this binary you will find (a number of) `REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_APP_KEY` strings but nothing named `xAppKey`. Depending on where in your code you place Richards suggestion `AppKey` may be visible at link time. But I don't know monotouch good enough to provide more details.