# MonoTouch binding to ObjectiveC library not working

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

the .h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum _XLBadgeManagedType {
    XLInboxManagedMethod = 0,
    XLDeveloperManagedMethod = 1
} XLBadgeManagedType ;


@interface XLXtifyOptions :NSObject
{
    NSString *xoAppKey;
    BOOL    xoLocationRequired ;
    BOOL    xoBackgroundLocationRequired ;
    BOOL    xoLogging ;
    BOOL    xoMultipleMarkets;
    XLBadgeManagedType xoManageBadge;
}
+ (XLXtifyOptions *)getXtifyOptions;
- (NSString *)getAppKey ;
- (BOOL) isLocationRequired;
- (BOOL) isBackgroundLocationRequired ;
- (BOOL) isLogging ;
- (BOOL) isMultipleMarkets;
- (XLBadgeManagedType)  getManageBadgeType;
- (void)xtLogMessage:(NSString *)header content:(NSString *)message, ...;
@end
```

the .m:

```
#import "XLXtifyOptions.h"
#import "XtifyGlobal.h"

static  XLXtifyOptions *xXtifyOptions=nil;

@implementation XLXtifyOptions

+ (XLXtifyOptions *)getXtifyOptions
{
    if (xXtifyOptions==nil) {
        xXtifyOptions=[[XLXtifyOptions alloc]init];
    }
    return xXtifyOptions;
}

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {        
        xoAppKey=xAppKey;
        xoLocationRequired=xLocationRequired;
        xoBackgroundLocationRequired=xRunAlsoInBackground ;
        xoLogging =xLogging ;
        xoMultipleMarkets=xMultipleMarkets;
        xoManageBadge=xBadgeManagerMethod;

    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)getAppKey
{
    return xoAppKey;
}
- (BOOL) isLocationRequired
{
    return xoLocationRequired;
}
- (BOOL) isBackgroundLocationRequired 
{
    return xoBackgroundLocationRequired;
}
- (BOOL) isLogging 
{
    return xoLogging;
}
- (BOOL) isMultipleMarkets
{
    return xoMultipleMarkets;
}
- (XLBadgeManagedType)  getManageBadgeType
{
    return xoManageBadge;
}
- (void)xtLogMessage:(NSString *)header content:(NSString *)format, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    if (xoLogging) {
        NSString *prettyFmt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", header,format];
        NSLogv(prettyFmt, args);
    }
    va_end(args);
}
@end
```

Global.h:

```
#define xAppKey @"abc123"

#define xLocationRequired NO

#define xRunAlsoInBackground FALSE    

#define xBadgeManagerMethod XLInboxManagedMethod 

#define xLogging TRUE

#define xMultipleMarkets FALSE
```

My binding definition:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
public interface XLXtifyOptions {

    [Static]
    [Export ("xtifyOptions")]
    XLXtifyOptions Options { get;}

    [Export ("getAppKey")]
    string GetAppKey ();

    [Export ("isLocationRequired")]
    bool IsLocationRequired ();

    [Export ("isBackgroundLocationRequired")]
    bool IsBackgroundLocationRequired ();

    [Export ("isLogging")]
    bool IsLogging ();

    [Export ("isMultipleMarkets")]
    bool IsMultipleMarkets ();

    [Export ("getManageBadgeType")]
    XLBadgeManagedType GetManageBadgeType ();

    //      [Export ("xtLogMessage:content:...")]
    //      void XtLogMessagecontent... (string header, string message,, );
    //      
}
```

These return null:

```
XLXtifyOptions.Options;
new XLXtifyOptions().GetAppKey();
```

The vendors instructions for getting started:

```
  XLXtifyOptions *anXtifyOptions=[Options getVendorOptions];
  [[TheirClass get ]initilizeXoptions:anVendorOptions];
```

I hastily tried to rename some things because I'm not sure how much of the vendor's code is ok to paste, so hopefully I didn't confuse matters.

This is related to: [Binding #define used as constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350740/binding-define-used-as-constant/15350825?noredirect=1#comment21685459_15350825)

**MORE INFORMATION:**

If I run this on a device rather than the simulator, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled managed exception: Wrapper type 'XtifyPush.XLXtifyOptions' is missing its native ObjectiveC class 'XLXtifyOptions'.
```

**EDIT**

re @Stephane: I updated the code to no longer obscure the vendor. What I am binding is: http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Getting+Started+with+Apple+Push+Notification+Service, fwiw. I updated the reference to getXtifyOptions as you recommended, but I have the same result. I got as far as I have with the github library you referenced, but I will keep digging.

The binding I am working on is available at: https://github.com/lordscarlet/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Xtify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this API has a horrible design, it relies on #define preprocessor directives for initial configurations like ApiKey, tons of spaces on headers... just to mention a few issues.

You can find a Binding Project here, please test it and tell me if it solves your issues.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2058130/random%20stuff/XtifyLib.zip

---

APIKey has not been set on your bindings.

Inside the SDK headers files, you will find `XLXtifyOptions.h` and `XLXtifyOptions.m` this means `XLXtifyOptions` class does not live inside the Static `XtifyPush` so I took both files, modified them a little bit and created another static fat (ARMv7, ARMv7s and i386) library called `libXtifyLibHelper.a`.

This library contains two helper objc messages `getXtifyOptionsWithAppKey:locationRequired:backgroundLocationRequired:logging:multipleMarkets:manageBadge:` and `getXtifyOptionsWithAppKey:` which will help you to correctly set the API key.

Please use one of the above helpers to set you API Key, those has been bound as static methods  inside XLXtifyOptions class.

As a side note you don't have to worry for `libXtifyLibHelper.a` it will be automagically (TM) be included inside your DLL when you build the provided project.

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: I changed to this answer because it fixed my actual problem. Stephane was a huge help above, and helped me work through some things, but this seems to have fully addressed all of the issues I was having.

Comment: Amazing News!! Glad I could Help

Answer (score 3):

The correct binding for `getVendorOptions` should looks like this:

```
[Static]
[Export ("vendorOptions")]
Options Options { get;}
```

the `get` part and the Capitalization is done by convention. Look at the code generated for this. GetAppKey is fine as long as you bind it as a method and not a property. Note that it shouldn't return null but throw an exception.

About

```
MyNamespace.Current;
```

I don't see any definition for it. So I don't know what's wrong.

At this point, I've some concerns on how your building your native library and including it inside of your managed one (re: the exception on the device). Make sure you're doing it right, look at tons of examples in https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it either. I am going to work on getting everything on to github or something in case someone is willing to look at the full scope of the binding and try to see if the issue is obvious. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: having your stuffs available would be, indeed, helpful

Comment: https://github.com/lordscarlet/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Xtify should allow you to bind and build just as I am. Thank you!

Comment: I'll work on putting a project together, but I'm simply doing this in the AppDelegate:

  `public AppDelegate ()
  {
   var xOptions = XLXtifyOptions.Options;
   var yOptions = new XLXtifyOptions ();
   XLappMgr.Current.InitializeXoptions (xOptions);
  }`

Comment: In creating sample code I am getting "Could not load file or assembly 'XtifyPush.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." I have the dll included, so I don't know if there is something wrong with the dll, but that could be an indication. I believe all of the native stuff should compile into the dll, correct?

Comment: "could not load": make sure you Xamarin.iOS is up to date. I know they changed the monotouch.dll signature lately

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr the Options class is not compiled

I had a look at your project and the functionality you're trying to bind. It looks like there's 2 parts, the embedded framework, which is distributed precompiled, and some other stuffs (mainly the Options class), including the `.h` that sets the `AppKey`, which **you** are supposed to compile in your app.

Unless you create a minimal `xcode` project doing that (and exposing a setter for the `AppKey`), there's no way your binding can work.

Another option is to ditch that part and implement XLXtifyOptions fully in C#, and then you're responsible for setting the AppKey yourself.

**UPDATE**: Some api calls of the compiled embeddedframework take the Options as parameter, so if you define the Options in C# only, make sure to add an `[Export]` attribute to every function or property defined in the Options.h file

Hope it helps and you get my point.

Comment: If I implement my own XLXtifyOptions, does my binding look sufficient for the rest of the functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your update -- would the `[Export]` sections somehow link to my class I created?

Comment: Making the minimal xcode app may be the easier way to go, at least based on my understanding so far. I would need a setter for everything in the Options.h file in that case, correct?

Comment: If I can export the XtifyGlobal.h, would that solve my problem altogether?

Comment: but you can't export it. If it was me, I'd create the Options in C#, I'm quite confident that will work best. Lemme add a 3rd answer

Answer (score 3):

As you need to build your own managed Options class, is how you could do it (in you Extra.cs file)

```
public class XLXtifyOptions : NSObject {
    static XLXtifyOptions options;
    [Export ("getXtifyOptions")] //not sure that one will be ever called by obj-C code
    public static XLXtifyOptions XtifyOptions () {
        return options ?? (options = new XLXtifyOptions () {
            appKey = "yourappkey",
        });
    }

    string appKey;

    [Export ("getAppKey")]
    public string GetAppKey () {
        return appKey;
    }

    //same for all the getters

    [Export ("getManageBadgeType")
    public XLBadgeManageType GetManageBadgeType () {
        return manageBadge;
    }

    //Have to check if this is the right way to bind method with variable lengths argument, but that's the idea
    [Export ("xtLogMessage:content:")]
    public void LogMessage (string header, params string[] message)
    {
        //print the message
    }
}

public enum XLBadgeManageType {
    Inbox,
    Developer
}
```

This should give you an idea...

Comment: This is looking great so far. My only question is that another class that is being bound calls XLXtifyOptions. I have this setup as a Binding project in Xamarin, and it can't compile because it doesn't see my class in extra.cs

  [Export ("initilizeXoptions:")]
  void InitializeXoptions (XLXtifyOptions xOptions);

EDIT: I have the same problem if I use btouch:

`XtifyLib.cs(99,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XLXtifyOptions' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Comment: I'm thinking that your answer is very helpful, but that I may have some larger issue. On the device I am getting a very similar error for `var x = new XLappMgr();`:

`Unhandled managed exception: Wrapper type 'XtifyPush.XLappMgr' is missing its native ObjectiveC class 'XLappMgr'.`

Comment: Ultimately, based on your other answers, I think I have the same problem with XLappMgr that I do with XLXtifyOptions. It is a .h, therefore it is not compiled into the code. Does that mean I need to do the same with it as I did the options, and roll my own in c#?

Comment: No. That header is the counterpart of a .m file which is compiled. The only .m that's not part of the framework is options.m

Comment: OK, then I still need to find out why I'm getting the Wrapper type missing error. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: remove the binding for the Option, use the managed version we just discussed, and the exception will be gone

Comment: If I remove the binding I get: `XtifyLib.cs(99,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XLXtifyOptions' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?` Will try to mess with the Makefile to see if its order of operations or something (not used to working with Makefiles). The github repo should have the changes we discussed.

Comment: Just to keep this neverending thread going: I got past botht he "type or namespace could not be found" and "Wrapper type is missing" errors. However, `XLappMgr.Manager` is returning null. This is what I have bound to `+(XLappMgr*)get;` with `  [Static]
  [Export ("get")]
  XLappMgr Manager { get; }
`

Comment: I was wrong, I am still getting `Unhandled managed exception: Wrapper type 'XtifyPush.XLappMgr' is missing its native ObjectiveC class 'XLappMgr'.` on the device, I just only get it if I try to fire the constructor for XLappMgr -- perhaps it doesn't have one?

Comment: FWIW: It seems that XLappMgr uses xAppKey based on running the sampleapp provided by the vendor. Will that be available the way this is put together, or would that fail?